# Is type="text/css" necessary in a <link> tag?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering whether or not it is necessary to use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=...>` over `<link rel="stylesheet" href=...>`. The `rel="stylesheet"` marks the information that it is a stylesheet - so `text/css` doesn't actually add anything as far as I'm concerned.

The only stylesheet format used by HTML is CSS anyway, so what does `text/css` 'say' to the browser? Some websites seem to add the `type="text/css"` attribute (http://www.jquery.com/), whilst other ones don't (http://www.youtube.com/).

So, what is the use of `type="text/css"` in a `<link rel="stylesheet">` element, and is it necessary to include it?

Comment: It may have been implemented to act as a fallback for servers which don't return the correct `MIME-type` on `.css` files, but it seems it wasn't ever necessary. I use it just for consistency's sake.

Comment: Something I just ran into, don't specify type="" or IE will not load your stylesheet.

Comment: Nowadays http://jquery.com/ site does not use `type="text/css"`, but the Stackoverflow site is still using it.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

It's not required with the HTML5 spec, but for older versions of HTML is it required.

**Html 4 W3.org spec**

http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/links.html#edef-LINK
http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/present/styles.html

Type stands for The MIME type of the style sheet.  The only supported value I have ever seen is Text/CSS, which is probably why HTML5 has dropped it.  I imagine they had it for earlier versions to allow future expansion possibilities which never happened.

Using HTML5 and not specifying the type, I have run so far into no problems with compatibility even when testing older versions of IE.

Comment: it may be required in the HTML4 spec, but no browsers actually enforce it.

Comment: well, there is a type for "image/ico"

Comment: Actually, the HTML4.01 spec does not appear to require the `type` attribute.

Answer (score 37):

It's not required, no.

The part of the HTML Living Standard you're interested in is [The `link` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-link-element), which states:

> A `link` element must have either a `rel` attribute or an `itemprop` attribute, but not both.
>
> The `type` attribute gives the MIME type of the linked resource. It is purely advisory. The value must be a valid MIME type string.
>
> For external resource links, the `type` attribute is used as a hint to user agents...

Comment: What does "as a hint to user agents..." mean? What are "user agents"?

Comment: @ScottyBlades Good question! A user agent is anything that can act on behalf of a user to download (in this case) HTML. Most of the time that's a web browser, but it could also be a terminal client like curl.

Answer (score 8):

HTML4.01 does not require the [`type`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-type-A) attribute on a [`<link>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3) tag. According to the specification, the `type` attribute is a hint to the browser. If the browser does not support the hinted content type, then it can skip fetching it.

> type = content-type [CI]
>
> > This attribute gives an advisory hint as to the content type of the content available at the link target address. It allows user agents to opt to use a fallback mechanism rather than fetch the content if they are advised that they will get content in a content type they do not support.
> >
> > Authors who use this attribute take responsibility to manage the risk that it may become inconsistent with the content available at the link target address.

- NOTE: `<link>` defers to `<a>`'s definition for the `type` attribute.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer => basically: only use type attribute if the browser may not support the type => useless for web standard files like CSS.

Answer (score 5):

My understanding is that it's to allow the specification of stylesheets in formats other than text/css.

While that has become the dominant (and standard) delivery format for stylesheets for (X)HTML documents, the specification is actually wide enough to allow a variety of different MIME types to be passed, it's just that standard browsers don't implement them.

Answer (score 2):

Not relevant to most people, but some systems (at least Microsoft SharePoint 2013) will use this type attribute when working out how to process HTML (e.g. when creating a .master page file).

Answer (score -1):

No it just stands for MIME type, it has been deprecated in HTML, We can drop using it without any browser compatibility.