# jquery.addClass() is not working on adding the already existing attribute with different value

Tags: jquery

I have a div with `style="display:none"`. On mouse hover on a link I want to show it by adding a class with `display=block` but it is not working.

Comment: Please add the code you tried

Comment: An inline style *overrides* all CSS classes from standard stylesheets (except those applied with `!important`). Best is to avoid use use of `style` entirely or use the `show()/hide()/toggle()` methods. Use the developer tools from your browser to inspect the matching CSS rules and the applied rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `!important` in class .[Check this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13746931/1723893) to see how `!important` works

```
 /*html*/
 <div class="first" style="display:none;">sdfirst</div>
 <div class="second" >second</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

  /*jquery*/   
  $(".second").mouseover(function() {

    $(".first").addClass("ss");
  })​

 /*css*/
​.ss{display:block !important;}​
```

[Specifics on CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body><div id="main">
          Mouse Over (click here for event) 
          <div id="div1" style="display:none">hello how are you</div>
        </div><script>
      var i = 0;
      $('#main').mouseover(function() {
            $('#div1').css('display','block');

      }).mouseout(function(){
        $('#div1').css('display','none');
      });

    </script></body>
    </html>
```

for add the you can use

```
       $('#div1').addClass("className");
```