# Strange IE8 behaviour

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

Recently published project in beta stage. Was testing it with new browsers for a while.

I fixed all bugs including background-size, some main css3 properties on IE8. 
The only issue on IE8 is following:

To quickly recreate the situation please enter to the website http://goo.gl/rlmelu and click on, for example, birthday. Then enter number of participiants, for example 30 and select some date. Then click "next".

That's how Firefox 26.0, Chrome shows result:

http://joxi.ru/3w7gUv3JTJDfEIXmJqM

And thats how IE8:

http://joxi.ru/Eg_gUv3JTJB-EJupfnA

Please don't tell me to not to use IE8.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: I love these IE8 Bugs :)

Comment: @CopyDevil then you must be IE8 familiar.

Comment: I'm on it, but a fiddle would be really helpful!

Comment: @CopyDevil Friend I show you working fiddle:) what else do you need. I can explain you any part.

Comment: @CopyDevil any success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Problem : The Choose Button

The Problem is CSS PIE.  
 Two possibilities:  
**Disable PIE**
In `iefixes.css`, disable PIE for `.btn`  
**Set to important**
Set the Background to important (But think about: [Is !important bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743671/is-important-bad-for-performance)):

```
.btn-warning{
    background-color: #f0ad4e !important;
}
```