# Does the :not pseudo class increase the specificity of a selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

I have read on css tricks that :not should not add additional specificity. But it looks like it does?

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/

> The specificity of the :not pseudo class is the specificity of its argument. The :not() **pseudo class does not add to the selector specificity, unlike other pseudo-classes.**

Or am I missing something?

```css
.red:not(.blue) {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="red">
</div>
```

Comment: Compare it to `.blue.red` instead, the `.red` still counts

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, it adds the specificity of its argument. Look at the first sentence:

> **The specificity of the :not pseudo class is the specificity of its argument.** The :not() pseudo class does not add to the selector specificity, unlike other pseudo-classes.

So the specificity of `.red:not(.blue)` is equal to that of `.red.blue` — 2 class selectors, or (0, 2, 0), making it more specific than `.red` on its own. What the second sentence means is that the `:not()` *itself* does not contribute the additional specificity of a pseudo-class to make it (0, 3, 0), like the `:hover` in `.red.blue:hover` does for example.

Comment: Curious , since stylesheets "cascade" why is `background: red;` not applied where it _follows_ `background: blue;` declaration ?

Comment: @guest271314: Because the first rule is more specific. This is a question about specificity, after all.

Comment: Can include description of `0,2,0` , `0,3,0` references at Answer ?

Comment: Good edit. It's really clear now how it works , thanks again!

Comment: @guest271314: I don't think it's really necessary to include a tutorial on calculating specificity in every answer on the topic. There are a number of resources online that will explain it better than I can in any individual answer

Comment: @BoltClock So what is the difference between :not and for example :has in terms of specificity? If I understood correctly only :not doesn't add any specificity by itself. Meaning any other pseudo selector should override :not cause it's stronger. In this demo it's not the case. DEMO :https://jsfiddle.net/j8rfqf29/

Comment: @Paran0a: You probably meant :matches, not :has. The specificity of :not and :matches is calculated the same way - take the specificity of its most specific argument. So .red:not(.blue) and .red:matches(.orange) are equally specific. But note that :matches isn't implemented on any other browser besides Safari 9 yet, so your demo isn't going to work as you expect on other browsers.

Comment: @BoltClock Ugh I had a brainfart. Yes I meant :matches. I understand now thanks.

Comment: A trick I've found occasionally useful for artificially increasing the specificity of a selector is to append `:not(.nosuchclassname)` or `:not(#nosuchid)` to it. Yes, it's ugly, but it's still better than resorting to `!important`.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: You don't even have to do that always - you can also simply repeat whichever simple selector is already in use, e.g. `.red.red` or `#id#id` (though it appears [the latter is bugged in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565928/idid-repeated-occurrences-of-the-same-simple-selector-should-increase-specif)). `:not()` does come in handy with type selectors, though - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299817/can-type-selectors-be-repeated-to-increase-specificity

Comment: @BoltClock: That requires the selector to already have a class or ID in it. Actually, my original use case for this trick was making a style like `a[rel=nofollow] { color: green }` (specificity 0,1,1; injected by a user script) take precedence over, say, `a#someid { color: black }` (specificity 1,0,1; already present in site style sheet). Using `a[rel=nofollow]:not(#nosuchid)` (specificity 1,1,1) does the trick. (Of course, `!important` would've worked too... except that it turned out some of the existing styles I wanted to override were *already* using `!important`.)

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: Ah. That's certainly a case for using `:not()`. You're much less likely to have an ID already in the selector than a class.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen: Oddly enough, a question just popped up with your *exact* use case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35062256/how-to-override-css-rule-with-id-selector Want to answer it, or may I in your place?

Comment: @BoltClock: [Answered.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35065825) Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 9):

The `:not` selector don't have it's own specificity, however the selector inside `:not()` do have.

[**From MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#Selector_Types)

> ### Selector Types
>
> The following list of selector types is by increasing specificity:
>
> 1. Type selectors (e.g., `h1`) and pseudo-elements (e.g., `:before`).
> 2. Class selectors (e.g., `.example`), attributes selectors (e.g., `[type="radio"]`) and pseudo-classes (e.g., `:hover`).
> 3. ID selectors (e.g., `#example`).
>
> **Universal selector (`*`), combinators (`+`, `>`, `~`, `' '`) and negation pseudo-class (`:not()`) have no effect on specificity. (The selectors declared inside `:not()` do, however.)**

---

As you're having the rule `.red:not(.blue)` and the element `<div class="red">` don't have the class `blue`, the rule is applied.

```css
.red:not(.blue) {
  background: blue;
}

.red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
div {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

Comment: Oh I'm dumb. I guess I totally misread what they were saying. Thank you.

Comment: 1) You need to use blockquote markup, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing 2) This doesn't really address the :not(). If anything, it reinforces the OP's confusion by restating that "the negation pseudo-class [has] no effect on specificity".

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock. #1 -> Done. #2 -> Just kept the doc links, so I think the confusion is removed.