# How to change CSS attribute at all div inside td with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, telerik

I use Telerik.. with SkinID
I am not sure, which wrong with my code..
At the aspx page the code just like this:

```
 <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2" align="center" class="to_center">
                                                            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnCLSave" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AddCL" OnClick="btnCLSave_Click"
                                                                Skin="" SkinID="RadButtonAdd" />
                                                            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnCLCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnCLCancel_Click"
                                                                Skin="" UseSubmitBehavior="False" SkinID="RadButtonReset" />
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
```

But after I run it, my page appears like this:
[image: UI]

I do not know which wrong..
But after I look at the source, some divs appears at the page.
[image: Code]

I try to add some style, like this:

```
.to_center div
        {
            display: inline;
        }
```

still not working.
I want that buttons to center. 
How to change CSS attribute display:none to display: inline to all divs inside that TD with class to_center using jquery?

Thank you

Comment: try `.to_center div { display: inline !important; }`

Comment: Correnct! Thank you very much, Sir... Can you explain? What is the meaning of !important ? at css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trying to set the style using css stylesheet, the problem is the inline style applied to the element which gets precedence over the style defined by you.

One possible solution is to use [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) if you want to define the style using stylesheet like

```
.to_center div { display: inline !important; }
```

Also read

- [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)
- [Is !important bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743671/is-important-bad-for-performance)