# Unable to remove bottom space for the Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin

Unable to remove the bottom space for the Bootstrap Navbar. When I go to inspect element, I can see that space is produced by the Navbar.

On changing the

> margin-bottom: 0px;

It got fixed on the screen, but when I get to change the same property in the bootstrap.css file. It is still showing the space below the navbar.

I am not sure what is the problem. It has already consumed much of my time for trying different solutions, but I got no success so far.

[image: Inspect Element]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load you custom css file after loading bootstrap.css. Then in your custom css file override the class (use the same selector as it is) and set the margin-bottom to 0. Avoid using !important ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743671/is-important-bad-for-performance#13743901)).

Answer (score 1):

change min-height:50px; to height:auto;