# Why do Website Checkers Give CSS !important a Negative Score?

Tags: css, performance, pagespeed

### Why do Website Checkers Give CSS !important a Negative Score?

When building a **performance driven** website that is quick to render, it is often recommended to remove any **CSS** `!important`.

However, I've read that it **doesn't** affect performance - See [is-important-bad-for-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743671/is-important-bad-for-performance).

Based on that, if correct, there must be another reason for `!important` receiving negative scores, but what could it be, or do website checkers use outdated algorithms?

> Note: This is **not** an SEO question. It is a website performance
>   question.

Comment: Because important is never needed. It's a lazy solution which can cause more global classes to be overridden.

Comment: I am sometimes forced to use them when adding custom CSS to a WordPress theme or plugin. So there is a good use case for them. But is there a performance issue or something else that can negatively affect a site?

Comment: *"I am sometimes forced to use them when adding custom CSS"* Then you are doing it wrong. Proper specificity will be more than adequate as would a proper WP theme fork.

Comment: Website checkers are opinionated - perhaps their definition of performance includes the maintenance cost of dealing with excessive use of !important, therefore all use of !important is negative.

Comment: I think, this is answering your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360190/is-it-bad-to-use-important-in-css-property

Answer (score 2):

If you rely on the `!important` property, the CSS file of yours will get bigger and bigger with every edit. That is not a good way to do work. If you have time please do not use `!important`. It is not meant to use on a regular basis. The program they use to determine the speed of website is setted  to gate `!important` as an extra property is not recommended. So if you do not require `!important`,
do not use it.  If it is an temporary work use it as it is not a big deal.