# firefox layout broken bootstrap

Tags: firefox, twitter-bootstrap

My layout is working fine in Chrome, Safari, and IE 9 but Firefox seems to be avoiding all twitter bootstrap styles thus leaving the page looking stunted and broken. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. I am using the most current version of Firefox. (18.0)

http://monooptical.com/

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten a s on css. You have:

```
<link href="http://monooptical.com/wp-content/themes/MonoTheme1.0/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/cs" rel='stylesheet' media="screen">
```

instead of:

```
<link href="http://monooptical.com/wp-content/themes/MonoTheme1.0/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel='stylesheet' media="screen">
```

Comment: MIME-type is not needed in HTML5: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409114/is-type-text-css-necessary-in-a-link-tag

Comment: @Scott Simpson Well, Firefox wouldn't link correctly to the css file with the type wrongly set (while it could if it wasn't set at all). I see monooptical has corrected it (although he didn't mark the answer as accepted) and it works. Go to the website and play a little with firebug to see what's happening.