# MIME type attribute irrelavant for stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

[Rails 3.2.13 stylesheet_link_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag) has `type` attribute.

```
stylesheet_link_tag "style" # =>
  <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

stylesheet_link_tag "style.css" # =>
  <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Whereas, [Rails 4.0.2 stylesheet_link_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag) examples says it does not has a `MIME type` attribute.

```
stylesheet_link_tag "style"
# => <link href="/assets/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />

stylesheet_link_tag "style.css"
# => <link href="/assets/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Is it a part of change in Rails >= 4.0 ?**

If I have read it right [html type attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_type.asp) - 
[Is type="text/css" necessary in a <link> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409114/is-type-text-css-necessary-in-a-link-tag)

Then the answer is - It's not required, no.