# Rails 4 stylesheet_link_tag missing "text/css" in HTML

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the stylesheet_link_tag in rails 4 and the outputted html is missing `type='text/css'`

I can't seem to find out how to add this to the stylesheet_link_tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is type="text/css" necessary in a <link> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409114/is-type-text-css-necessary-in-a-link-tag)

Comment: Please post your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `type` option in your `stylesheet_link_tag` helper:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', type: 'text/css'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be automatic in your `application.html.erb`

```
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
</head>
```