# CSS button creator link using html

Tags: html, css

I have created a button on a CSS button generator cannot link it to display in browser. 
A button is generating to the browser however it is just a standard html button. 
The current code is:

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


.btn {
  background: #3498db;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 38px;
  padding: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}


<button type = "btn">Entry forms</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: put the css code between a <head><style></style></head> and this <button type = "btn">Entry forms</button> is <button class="btn">Entry forms</button>

Comment: How can I link the CSS code to my button and display it in a browser.

Comment: You might want to check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `btn` class in your HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Entry forms</button>
```

Also, your CSS needs to be inside `<style>` tags in the `<head>` section of your HTML.

**Update: full code**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .btn {
      background: #3498db;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
      -webkit-border-radius: 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 0;
      border-radius: 0px;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 38px;
      padding: 40px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .btn:hover {
      background: #3cb0fd;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="btn">Entry forms</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So replace the "button type" line and replace with class?

Comment: I just tried this and the button is still not displaying in chrome

Comment: thanks for your answer. I noticed that you defined the style tags to type "text/css" why is this? why not leave the style tags as <style></stlye>? Thanks :)

Comment: HTML5 and most modern browsers don't need it, I just include it out of habit. This answers a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409114/is-type-text-css-necessary-in-a-link-tag

Comment: Also take a look at http://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient because the last several versions of all the major browsers do not require `linear-gradient` to be prefixed. That could help reduce your CSS quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

No problems. You just need to add the class "btn". I added some styles to improve it.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    button.btn {
      background: #3498db;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
      -webkit-border-radius: 0;
      -moz-border-radius: 0;
      border-radius: 0px;
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
      font-family: Arial;
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 38px;
      padding: 40px;
      text-decoration: none;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    button.btn:hover {
      background: #3cb0fd;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="btn">Entry forms</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, to make it even more sure, you can add the code below to all your buttons.
(Note: It will not style the button on hover)

```html
<button style="background: #3498db;
          background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
          background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
          background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
          background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3498db, #2980b9);
          background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
          -webkit-border-radius: 0;
          -moz-border-radius: 0;
          border-radius: 0px;
          text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #666666;
          font-family: Arial;
          color: #ffffff;
          font-size: 38px;
          padding: 40px;
          text-decoration: none;
          border: none;
          border-radius: 5px;
          cursor: pointer;">Entry forms</button>
```