# Is it still necessary to use the rel="stylesheet" attribute value for the <link> tag in HTML5?

Tags: html, css

I know in HTML 4 it's necessary, but is that still so regarding HTML5? I only ask because I heard in HTML5 it is not necessary.

Comment: Over here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409215/14955) they say you need either a `rel` or a `itemprop` attribute.

Answer (score 8):

The `rel` is required  because it  specifies the relationship between the current document and the linked document.

Answer (score -1):

It is required to mention in html5 because it define the relation between current document and the linked style document.

Comment: You came here 6 year later to copy the top answer?