# Why is my css not connecting to my html?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a folder with a `home.html`, `home.css`, and an image folder.

for some reason my html file will not utilize my css file.

these are the stylesheet lines located in the head of the html file

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="home.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I was able to make the html display a desired image in the jumbotron with

```
<img src="img/SANDLOTS_Logo_DESIGN_08242016.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
```

so I believe I am able to creating the correct path, but for some reason I still cant get my custom css to take effect.

my file structure is:

```
sandlots
---home.css
---home.html
---img
---------'img/SANDLOTS_Logo_DESIGN_08242016.jpg'
```

I have also tried just inserting the css in the html like so

```
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        .body {
        background-image: url('img/SANDLOTS_Logo_DESIGN_08242016.jpg');

}
    </style>
```

Comment: You should have to show the folder structure as well.

Comment: Try an inspect element to see if your CSS actually is being used, but is also being overridden by other CSS.

Comment: Does the selector match any element in the DOM? What does `document.querySelectorAll(".body").length` say if you run it in the Console of the Developer Tools?

Comment: Why not just put all of your css inline? OR, play around with your file path naming until it works. Those pesky [..] dots and slashes [/]

Comment: @wahwahwah — The question clearly states that putting all the CSS inline **doesn't solve the problem**!

Comment: You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: can you put the content of the 2 files on a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/)?

Answer (score 0):

if your internal styles are working properly, the problem is from your linking or path of your files.

but, if your internal styles are not working as well, the problem might be from your selectors.

if you mean the body tag by selecting **.body**, there is no need to put **.** before the body. just write **body{}** .

Answer (score -2):

Did you forget `type="text/css"`. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409146) it necessary for older html versions.

Comment: Browsers don't really care about HTML versions. No modern browser requires a `type` attribute. I'm not aware of any historical browser that required it. The linked answer is wrong anyway: It links to the DTD as supporting evidence, but it marks the `type` attribute as `#IMPLIED`.