# Specifying the type property in a link statement

Tags: html, css

In a HTML file when linking to a stylesheet document, not specifying the type property makes any difference to the output or makes it more time efficient?

For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
```

Comment: Posible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409114/is-type-text-css-necessary-in-a-link-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find discussion about `type` attribute relevance [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409114/is-type-text-css-necessary-in-a-link-tag).

From that, you can deduce that this attribute is not required. Before HTML5 it was required, but in HTML5 it was dropped.

It doesn't make any difference if you are using this attribute or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not required with the HTML5 spec, but for older versions of HTML is it required.
I have run so far into no problems with compatibility even when testing older versions of IE.