# What does <link type=“”> do to your file?

Tags: html, css

I am aware that this tag specifies the type of file you link to(typically “text/css”) for  but why do we need to add that?

Comment: With HTML5 you don't need to add type attribute. For older version of HTML the type attribute is used to mention the type of file you are trying to add to your page.

Comment: This is clearly stated in the specification: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#attr-link-type

Comment: possibly duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409114/is-type-text-css-necessary-in-a-link-tag

Answer (score 1):

type atribute in link tag describes the linked resource's media type.

In most cases, you can safely omit type without any negative consequences, but it's a good idea to specify it to avoid problems in the future.

Read more: https://html.com/attributes/link-type/#ixzz5mrFahTtr

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do anything to the file per se. It is analogous to mime type header info for the type of document... I suspect it was added to give the browser context the page author's intended use of the file (without the actual overhead of having to retrieve/read the file and header / mime type info of the file or loading it when referenced-- ie. speed when loading).

It might have also allowed multiple file mime types to effectively get handled the same way by the browser at some point in html's rich history. Today this attribute is often not required or omitted depending on the markup language.